# How can I limit the user input to only certain integers (ie: Only between 1-100, which also includes 1 and 100) in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a Guess the number game for my Computing homework but I dont't know how to limit the user to only input certain integers (ie: 1-100, also including 1 and 100) This is my code so far:

```
import random

BOUNDS = (1, 100)
TRIES_ALLOWED = 6

the_number = random.randint(*BOUNDS)

print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!\n")
print("I'm thinking of a number between %d and %d." % BOUNDS)
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.")
print("You only have 6 attempts to guess the number.\n")

for tries in range(TRIES_ALLOWED):
guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))

if guess > 100:
    print ('That is an error please enter a number between 1 and 100')

if guess < 1:
    print ('That is an error please enter a number between 1 and 100')

if guess > the_number:
    print("The number is lower")
elif guess < the_number:
    print("The number is higher")
else:
    print("You guessed it! The number was %d" % (the_number))
    print("And it only took you %d tries!\n\n" % (tries + 1))
    break
else:
print("You failed to guess in time!\n\n")
```

It would be greatly appreciated if you could help me out

Comment: the only thing I see wrong with your code is the indentation, could you please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37330288/edit) your post and fix it up?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this Basic Code for selection a number between 1 and 100

```
import random
num = random.randint(1, 100)
while True:
    print('Guess a number between 1 and 100')
    guess = input()
    i = int(guess)
    if i == num:
        print('You won!!!')
        break
    elif i < num:
               print('Try Higher')
    elif i > num:
               print('Try Lower')
#any recommendations for the game end
print('if you gussed less than 6 times you won')
```

Comment: note that the OP already has some code written, theirs also implements a `TRIES_ALLOWED` so I'm not sure how helpful this will be.

Answer (score 0):

```
def prompt_number_range(start, end):
    while True:
        prompt_str = "Please enter a number within the range {0} - {1}:".format(start, end)
        try:
            user_input = raw_input(prompt_str)
        except NameError:
            user_input = input(prompt_str)
        try:
            input_as_int = int(user_input)
            if start <= input_as_int <= end:
                return input_as_int
            else:
                print("that is not within the given boundaries")
        except ValueError:
            pass

print (prompt_number_range(1,100))
```

You can view a run of the above here:
https://ideone.com/9mtoOt (Python 3)
https://ideone.com/W6hRGh (Python 2.7)

The following is the above code merged into your code fully functioning:

```
import random


def prompt_number_range(start, end):
    while True:
        prompt_str = "Please enter a number within the range {0} - {1}:".format(start, end)
        try:
            user_input = raw_input(prompt_str)
        except NameError:
            user_input = input(prompt_str)
        try:
            input_as_int = int(user_input)
            if start <= input_as_int <= end:
                return input_as_int
            else:
                print("that is not within the given boundaries")
        except ValueError:
            pass

BOUNDS = (1, 100)
TRIES_ALLOWED = 6
the_number = random.randint(*BOUNDS)

print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!\n")
print("I'm thinking of a number between %d and %d." % BOUNDS)
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.")
print("You only have 6 attempts to guess the number.\n")
for tries in range(TRIES_ALLOWED):
    user_guess = prompt_number_range(*BOUNDS)
    if user_guess == the_number:
        print("You guessed it! The number was %d" % (the_number))
        print("And it only took you %d tries!\n\n" % (tries + 1))
        break
    elif the_number < user_guess:
        print("The number is lower")
    elif the_number > user_guess:
        print("The number is higher")
else: #for loop finished normally without breaking
    print("You failed to guess in time!\n\n")
```

Comment: note that the OP already has some code written, theirs also implements a `TRIES_ALLOWED` so I'm not sure how helpful this will be.

Comment: you also may notice that the OP has parentheses around all `print` statements and is using `input` instead of `raw_input` so I'd guess that Ekansh is using python 3 so this will not even run as it is,

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Tries allowed can be handled externally (as it should be). Thanks for the python 2 vs 3 catch, I've now made my solution python 2 and 3 compatible.

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
import random

BOUNDS = (1, 100)
TRIES_ALLOWED = 6
win = False
the_number = random.randint(*BOUNDS)

print("\tWelcome to 'Guess My Number'!\n")
print("I'm thinking of a number between %d and %d." % BOUNDS)
print("Try to guess it in as few attempts as possible.")
print("You only have 6 attempts to guess the number.\n")

for tries in range(TRIES_ALLOWED):
    guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))

    if guess > 100:
        print ('That is an error please enter a number between 1 and 100')
        continue

    elif guess < 1:
        print ('That is an error please enter a number between 1 and 100')
        continue

    if guess > the_number:
        print("The number is lower")
    elif guess < the_number:
        print("The number is higher")
    elif guess == the_number:
        win = True
        break

if win == True:
    print("You guessed it! The number was %d" % (the_number))
    print("And it only took you %d tries!\n\n" % (tries + 1))

elif win == False:
    print("You failed to guess in time!\n\n")
```

Output (example):
[image: Output]

Comment: this is almost identical to the OP's code except that the indentation is fixed and you slightly changed the handling of the "winning" text.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are asking for?

```
>>> number1 = -1
>>> number2 = 1
>>> number3 = 100
>>> number4 = 101
>>> number5 = 34
>>> BOUNDS = (1, 100)
>>> for number in number1, number2, number3, number4, number5:
...   print(number in range(BOUNDS[0], BOUNDS[1] + 1))
... 
False
True
True
False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

If your only problem with this code is input validation, you can replace this whole block:

```
guess = int(input("Take a guess: "))

if guess > 100:
    print ('That is an error please enter a number between 1 and 100')

if guess < 1:
    print ('That is an error please enter a number between 1 and 100'
```

With this:

```
guess = None
while guess not in range(1,101):
    guess = int(raw_input("Enter a number between 1 and 100:"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
weight = float(input("bag weight "))
while weight<1.01 or weight>3:
        weight=float(input("Give bag weight between 1.01 and 3 :"))
```

[image]

Comment: (1) The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)). (2) We don't allow images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow.